# English equivalent or Expression for "Who take care of a Pregnant Mother"

Tags: meaning, expressions

English is not my language and I need help with this...

I need create a name for an mobile app that will help pregnant womens for 9 months giving tips about everything about she and her babe.

So ... I need a English equivalent or Expression for "Who take care of a Pregnant Mother". Would be "Mommy's Carer" ?

Thank you all that can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word which is gaining currency in Britain at least for a person performing this role, is *doula*.

> **doula** /ˈduːlə /
>
> A woman who gives support, help, and advice to another woman during pregnancy and during and after the birth:
>   *from admission through delivery, a doula stayed at her assigned patient’s side*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doula)]

It's actually a Modern Greek word. ODO gives its etymology from Ancient Greek δουλη *doulē,* female slave.

Comment: What's wrong with *midwife*?

Comment: Nothing, except that these days midwives don't tend to walk through the pregnancy with the expectant mother. They are Royal College-qualified and there for crises and the birth. This may be due to Health Service funding; doulas tend to be private-sector and not Royal College-qualified midwives.

Comment: Last experience I had of a midwife was thirty-two years ago when our youngest child was born. On that occasion a senior and a junior hospital midwife not only took charge of the entire birthing process (a doctor called by to offer congratulations and take a look at the new-born boy), but in the few weeks following a 'community midwife' fought through snowdrifts to get into our village to check on mother and baby. That was the free-of-charge National Health Service in January 1982!

Answer (score 2):

In Britain such a person is called a *midwife*. These are nurses who have done additional training in 'midwifery'. They care for mothers-to-be before, during and after the birth of the child and give advice on everything from morning sickness to breast feeding. They are also qualified to supervise the mother's labour and the birthing process.

In some countries this work is done by doctors, but in Britain midwives mostly take exclusive care of all uncomplicated births.  Obstetricians are often only called upon if problems arise. The practice dates from times when birthing was supervised by wise women. Today it is a highly skilled profession with rigorous training.

I believe that Commonwealth countries such as Canada, Australia and New Zealand have midwives. I am not sure about the United States. Other European countries have similar professionals. In France a midwife is a *sage-femme*.

Comment: _Midwife_ is also a much more familiar term than _doula_, which may make it a better choice for an app name.